# Saving data to Firebase with REST

Tags: rest, curl, firebase

**I'm using Firebase to store application tokens with names, using the REST api.**

*This is the data structure I'm using:*

[image: Firebase data structure]

*This is the data structure after I add a new application.*
[image: Firebase data structure after]

*This is the command I use.*

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"3ba7792jae16328\":{\"name\":\"Test 2\"}}" \ https://xxx.firebaseio.com/apps.json
```

I don't want the unique ID that the POST request adds to my data structure. I already tried with a PUT request but it override all the data inside the "apps" node. Anyways this is the PUT command I tried.

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"3ba7792jae16328\":{\"name\":\"Test 2\"}}" \ https://xxx.firebaseio.com/apps.json
```

**Is there another way to add data and preserve my structure?**

(Use the auto generated POST tokens as my own application tokens is not a valid answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your self-generated ID *into* the URL:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\":{\"name\":\"Test 2\"}" \ https://xxx.firebaseio.com/apps/3ba7792jae16328.json
```

Firebase always overwrites (unless you use [`PATCH`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-patch)) the entire node at the URL you indicate. So it's important that you specify the URL up to the level that you want to overwrite data.

Comment: Thanks @Frank I used this command based on yours to add new entries. `curl -X POST -d "{\"name\":\"Test 2\"}" \ https://xxx.firebaseio.com/apps/hi90210bet3b357.json`

Comment: And the POST token. Isn't there a way to take out that? Anyways thanks, you gave the right answer.

Comment: If you mean whether the command can run without the `-X POST` parameter, then I'm not sure. Firebase follows a REST-ful pattern here, data updates require `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH` verb for data updates. If you can get curl to issue one of those verbs without using `-X POST` that would solve it. Alternatively Firebase has a "Method Override", but that'll just replace the `-X POST` with something longer: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-method-override

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- if you want to add on row:

  method: PUT

  url: `https://yourID.firebaseio.com/pages/your_object_name.json`

  data:

  ```
  {
    "1": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "page 4"
    }
  }
  ```
- if you want to add multiple rows:

  methode: PATCH

  url: `https://yourID.firebaseio.com/pages.json`

  data:

  ```
  {
    "1": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "page 4"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "page 4"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "page 4"
    }
  }
  ```